# Embed Internet Explorer browser into Winforms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, web, ip

I'm trying to open a IP specified webpage using IE (Why IE? Because not every Windows have Chrome or Firefox installed) and present it in a simple Winforms window.

The up-mentioned webpage is a BI (Business Intelligence) webpage that will update itself dynamically, and I want the user to sit and look at it while the page is updated with a new statistics.

Flow of events:

- User will enter the specific IP address and click "Get the Web-page".
- New Winform window will pop-up with the specific webpage inside.

Also, it will be great if there an option to hide IE navigation panel, because I don't want to give the option of browsing in this window.

I tried to do this using CefSharp, but I didn't get to anywhere. Every example that I saw was written in asp.

Here is was I did so far, and this is not working:

```
namespace BingoDesktopWindow
{
    public partial class BingoWin : Form
    {
        public BingoWin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);

            ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://12.345.67.89/bingo/Default.html");
            this.browserPanel.Container.Add(browser);
        }
    }
```

Thank you!
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do not you use Winforms WebBrowser control. [WinForms WebBrowserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx). You can manipulate it more than IE. Web browser control is itself derived from IE so, it has all its functionalities.

Comment: Thank you. The answer was right under my nose and I didn't notice it. WebBrowserControl worked perfectly, but apparently our web application can't work flawlessly with IE. It must be loaded by Google Chrome. I solved the problem with WebKit  ([link](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/tutorials.php))

Comment: There are a few problems with the WebBrowser control. E.g. its default emulation mode is IE 7 and you will have to change registry value to make it simulate other IE versions. Also even if it simulates, say IE 11, it still lacks some feature of a real IE 11. E.g. the textarea element in a real IE 11 supports spell-check-as-you-type, but the WebBrowser control doesnt.