# Chrome Web Browser Control - VS2008 C# Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome, visual-studio-2008, webbrowser-control

### Question

I need a chrome web browser control in **Visual Studio 2008 : C# windows form**.

### Why i want to use a different control

Below is the message i am getting when i try to use it from Web Browser Control
[image]

### Things that i have tried

1. **CefSharp** (GitHub) - It works but for higher version than VS 2008.
2. [Registry to change default browsing control](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version) - not working

Comment: As far as I know you can't get browser specific but there is a browser control you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624988/embed-internet-explorer-browser-into-winforms-using-c-sharp

Comment: @jaredbaszler he is using "CefSharp" which only works for VS2010 and greater

Comment: So your saying you want to stick with CefSharp but you want it to work in VS2008?  If so, you'll have to make that request to the CefSharp developers.  Otherwise you'll need to make the native WinForms web browser control work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jaredbaszler i never said i want to stick to "CefSharp" you posted that link in the comment.

Comment: My first post included a link that has an accepted answer referencing the native `WinForms WebBrowser` control to someone asking a similar question that you are.  Does the `WebBroswer` control work for your needs?

Comment: @jaredbaszler no it doesn't because when i try to navigate through a bank site it says "javascript is disabled in the browser" but when i go to the control panel, it shows that the javascript is ON for the browser and same when i go to the Internet Explorer it shows the same thing that is why i want to check it with a different browser control.

Comment: You can supress errors from the WebBrowser control: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15230105/3705348.  I'm not sure if that is an option for you but the settings in IE and/or Chrome would not affect the errors you are getting from the `WebBrowser` control as it is independent of the regular browsers.

Comment: @jaredbaszler i have updated the question which includes the image of that error. Please tell me how to fix it and btw i have already written this code "webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;"

Comment: Give `DotNetBrowser` library a try - that seems to be the most recent alternative to the native `WebBrowser` control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome

Comment: @jaredbaszler nice answer but it is for 2010 and above and the only reason i am sticking to 2008 is bcoz VS and Crystal report are directly link and instead dont have to be used seperately.