# Open a Webpage inside a C# form (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to open a webpage inside a winforms application?

I had an idea of importing some sort of webdrivers into the application.
Also, i tried opening an instance of the browser in my application, but it opens in a different window altogether.

I'm facing following limitations with `WebBrowser` control:

1. I am not able to calculate the page load time.
2. There is a frame drop in the media in some of the media formats.

Comment: You can simply use default `WebBrowser` control. But it seems like you are trying to solve another problem. Describe **why** you want to open a webpage inside a C# form.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624988/embed-internet-explorer-browser-into-winforms-using-c-sharp

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I'm aware of the WebBrowser control which can open up basic webpages inside a winform application. But media stream fails in this control.

Comment: If the standard control doesn't work, and you can't use third party controls, I am not sure exactly how you think we can help?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [DotNetBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) library. It provides Chromium-based WPF and WinForms browser controls, which are quite easy to embed into .NET application. It supports all the modern web standards including HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. The rendered page looks exactly like in Google Chrome.
The library is commercial, however it is free for use in Open-Source and Academic projects. 
Is available as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetBrowser/)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DotNetBrowser;
using DotNetBrowser.WinForms;

namespace WinForms.DotNetBrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BrowserView browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView();
            Controls.Add((Control) browserView);
            browserView.Browser.LoadURL("http://www.youtube.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. But i can't use third party libraries in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely possible... you can just do it with `WebBrowser` control. Place it to your form and call `Navigate` method:

```
browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: WebBrowser control has some limitations to it which restricts me from using it.

Comment: limitations like?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options available:-

- WebBrowser Control

> With the WebBrowser control, you can add Web browser functionality to your application. The control works like a Web browser by default.

- [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/)

> CefSharp is the the easiest way to embed a full-featured standards-complaint web browser into your C# or VB.NET app.

Comment: CefSharp seems to be a promising framework. And thank you so much for your time and efforts. But i can't use third party libraries or frameworks in my project.